# Yasnippet increment function name

Tags: yasnippet

I have a small snippet like this:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: options
# key: vop
# --
var options = {
    target:        '#$1',
    beforeSubmit:  showRequest,
    success:       showResponse
}$0
```

What I would like to do is to increment function name for each insertion. Like this:

```
var options1 = {
  target:        '#',
  beforeSubmit:  showRequest,
  success:       showResponse
}

var options2 = {
  target:        '#',
  beforeSubmit:  showRequest,
  success:       showResponse
}
```

etc... Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in yasnippet you can use elisp code, so it's easy:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: options
# key: vop
# --
var options`(if (boundp 'vop-count) (setq vop-count (1+ vop-count)) (setq vop-count 1) ) (vop-count)` = {
    target:        '#$1',
    beforeSubmit:  showRequest,
    success:       showResponse
}$0
```

If you wanna reset the counter, run `(setq vop-count 0)`

Comment: Thank you. But since I've less than 15 reputation I guess I can not choose it as accepted answer.

Comment: @Erdem really? I didn't know that. It seems stupid since the this site should welcome newcomers. Anyway, glad to help :)

Comment: @Erdem 15 reputation is the threshold for upvoting, you should still be able to accept the answer. http://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers, http://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/privileges

Comment: @npostavs after your post I recognized the accept answer button. But it looks faint so I couldn't recognize it until now.